# SQL Counting Multiple Rows as One Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Can someone help me.
Here's what I'm trying to do. 
I have a table:

```
**tblColors**
id    color_name
1      red
2      blue
3      white
4      white
5      blue
6      red
7      blue
8      white
9      red
10     blue
```

For example I accept 3 user inputs which are: 
1. red
2. blue
3. white

I want to count how many sets of these 3-colors are present in my database. (red-blue-white) 
In my sample database the answer should be:

```
**tblColors**
id    color_name
------------------>id 1-3 is my first set of (red-blue-white)
1      red
2      blue
3      white
------------------

4      white
5      blue

-------------------------->id 6-8 is my second set
6      red
7      blue
8      white
--------------------------
9      red
10     blue
```

I have 2 (red-blue-white) set in my database so the result should be: 2 
Sorry the description of the problem is not that clear but I hope you get the picture.

Comment: Why don't you have a unique index on `color_name`? What is the purpose of `**` in your answer? I don't see logical groups. Do you want to have the common maximum count of these colors?

Comment: So you want to count if there is a sequence of red, blue and white?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter hi, I edited my post. pls review the answer to my post to see what i want to count.

Comment: @deterministicFail yes exactly. any ideas?

Comment: @TimSchmelter im using mySQL. and regarding your first question, I was told to create this simple database that will accept any color name regardless if that color_name is already in the database.

Comment: @irayan05: is the order relevant (look at the comment on [Giannis answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198449/284240))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   tblColors T1
       LEFT JOIN tblColors T2
           ON T1.id = T2.id - 1
       LEFT JOIN tblColors T3
           ON T2.id = T3.id - 1
WHERE  T1.color_name + '-' +
       T2.color_name + '-' +
       T3.color_name = 'red-blue-white'
```

**[Fiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dd44/6)**

Comment: +1 even if it's not clear whether `white-blue-red`  should be counted or not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Based on OPs eaxample, the order of the colors does matter.

Comment: Yes, but in most cases sample data on SO is inappropriate. So as long OP doesn't confirm this it's not set in stone. OP stated: _"I want to count how many sets of these 3-colors are present in my database"_ A [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is by definition unordered: "the order in which the elements of a set are listed is irrelevant (unlike for a sequence or tuple)"

Comment: hi @GiannisParaskevopoulos, thanks a lot this is exactly what im trying to do. Thank you so much prof.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  sorry for my unclear description my english is not so good, im sure you could've answered if the problem is clear. thanks anyway.

Comment: @irayan05: note that could fail if someone enters a color like `red-blue` or `blue-white`.